# After versioning a file still new image isn't reflecting in the web page

Tags: css, versioning

```
div#main {
    background: url("../images/visual.png") no-repeat scroll 
center center  #325a8d;
    float: left;
    height: 530px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 255;    
}
```

above code is in the css file and I versioned that file as well as I have changed the visual.png image with the other image which is specified in there. Now when I loaded the web page I can see my new CSS file has been loaded but my new image wasn't reflected which seems like cached. when i hard loaded the page that i found the new image. How to get the new image without hard reloading the page?

Comment: any working example, that shows your problem ?

Comment: I have with me but can't share here

Answer (score 0):

Add the version number to where you include your style.css like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="LarsWeber-style-css" href="https://example.com/style.css?ver=0.0.1" type="text/css" media="all">
```

As long as you update the `?ver=X.X.X` part of the link you will force the browser to reload the stylesheet without the cache.

For development purposes you can also just work in Incognito Mode of the browser of your choice

Comment: Hi @joscha my new CSS file getting loaded properly but my new image isn't getting loaded. for example, previously my image size was 100kb and my new image size is 50kb, so here in this situation, my 100kb image is getting loaded. 
 When I hard reload the page I can see the new image i.e 50kb.

Comment: Seems like your browser is still caching the image. Did you change the image name? In the past I had problems when using the same name for an image.

Comment: HI @joscha I didn't change the image name but I uploaded the same image with different size.

Comment: @MiteshBhanushali Then try alternating the image name. The browser caching is too agressive here. Either that or work in ingocnitio mode during development. Once in production you shouldn't change images using css anyways